# join rows in same table + oracle

Tags: oracle

```
  I have a table MNO like this:-



 key    open  mode  close     time
   1    112    O             10:15pm
   1           C     200     11:50pm
```

I want the output of query to give me this:-

```
key  open   close   difference  open_time   close_time
1    112     200      88         10:15pm      11:50pm
```

Comment: I tried 'select 
key, nvl(sum(decode(mode,'O',open)),0) open, nvl(sum(decode(mode,'C',close)),0) close, nvl(sum(decode(mode,'C',close)),0) - nvl(sum(decode(mode,'O',open)),0) difference from MNQ group by key; '  but I am not able to group by the time

Answer (score 2):

```
select
 o.key, o.open, c.close, 
 c.close - o.open as difference,
 o.time as open_time,
 c.time as close_time
from 
  mno o
  mno c
where
  o.key = c.key
and o.mode='O'
and c.mode='C'
;
```

Comment: thanks a ton schurik. that worked. thanks stackoverflow team.